# Set Muti-Index by column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with  columns I would like to make a multi-index by grouping the like valued entries in one column

```
A a 3
B c 2
A d 1
A e 4
B a 5
```

becomes

```
A a 3
  d 1
  e 4
B c 2
  a 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the index as the first two columns and then sort it.

```
# create data
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'B'},
                   'col2': {0: 'a', 1: 'c', 2: 'd', 3: 'e', 4: 'a'},
                    'col3': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 4, 4: 5}})
# set and sort index
df.set_index(['col1', 'col2']).sort_index(level=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Output

```
           col3
col1 col2      
A    a        3
     d        1
     e        4
B    a        5
     c        2
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of being obnoxious and providing an answer without reference to column names because none were given

```
df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.values[:, :2].T)).iloc[:, -1].sort_index()

A  a    3
   d    1
   e    4
B  a    5
   c    2
dtype: int64
```

---

That said, please pick @TedPetrou's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `groupby` with aggregate function:

```
df = df.groupby(['1', '2']).sum()
```

Just change `1` and `2` with column names.